# Do attribute names consume memory on instance basis in python

Tags: python, cpython, slots, python-internals

Considering I have millions of objects with 3 `__slots__`

Is it more memory efficient to have short slot names like `x` vs. long like `would_you_like_fries_with_that_cheeseburger`?

Or are the names allocated only once per class (opposed to once per instance?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Names for slots only take memory per class, not per instance.

Slots use [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) that map directly into the memory reserved for an instance, and the attribute names are mapped to these descriptors on the class.

Thus, the length of the names has no influence on how much memory each instance uses for the slots; the names only take space in the `__dict__` attribute on the class (mapping name to descriptor), and in the descriptor object itself (to provide a string representation of the object); the string is interned even.

You can check how the custom descriptors are given their state in the [C source code for `type.__new__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/799722cb0ddb90752cde7798cab543f30623ebf2/Objects/typeobject.c#L2758-L2776) (responsible for creating class objects):

```c
if (et->ht_slots != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < nslots; i++, mp++) {
        mp->name = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(
            PyTuple_GET_ITEM(et->ht_slots, i));
        if (mp->name == NULL)
            goto error;
        mp->type = T_OBJECT_EX;
        mp->offset = slotoffset;

        /* __dict__ and __weakref__ are already filtered out */
        assert(strcmp(mp->name, "__dict__") != 0);
        assert(strcmp(mp->name, "__weakref__") != 0);

        slotoffset += sizeof(PyObject *);
    }
}
```

where `mp->offset` is the index into the memory for the instance.

The descriptor used is a [`PyMemberDescr_Type` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/799722cb0ddb90752cde7798cab543f30623ebf2/Objects/descrobject.c#L692-L729), whose `member_get` function uses the (very generic) [`PyMember_GetOne()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/799722cb0ddb90752cde7798cab543f30623ebf2/Python/structmember.c#L7-L91); with the offset the pointer is retrieved from the instance:

```c
PyMember_GetOne(const char *addr, PyMemberDef *l)
{
    PyObject *v;


    addr += l->offset;
```

`addr` is the memory address of the instance. The rest of the function deals with various types of members; the slot member is always set to type `T_OBJECT_EX`:

```c
case T_OBJECT_EX:
    v = *(PyObject **)addr;
    if (v == NULL)
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AttributeError, l->name);
    Py_XINCREF(v);
    break;
```

which the function then returns; if the attribute was never set (and so `v == NULL`) an `AttributeError` exception is raised.

Comment: Hi, it should be T_OBJECT_EX, if slot not be set, am I right?

Comment: @roachsinai yes, good catch! The difference being that an AttributeError is raised when it’s not set.